# Как передать данные компоненту из контейнера в роутере?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Возможно не правильно сформулировал вопрос, сейчас на пальцах объясню что имею ввиду:

Вот мой роутер:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'

import App from './containers/App'
import Publication from './containers/Publication';

import NotFound from './components/NotFound'
import PublicationList from './components/PublicationList';
import PublicationForm from './components/PublicationForm';
import PublicationSetting from './components/PublicationSetting';

export const routes = (
  <div>
    <Route path='/' component={App}>
      <Route path='publications' component={Publication}>
          <IndexRedirect to='list' />
          <Route path='list' component={PublicationList} />
          <Route path='form' component={PublicationForm} />
          <Route path='setting' component={PublicationSetting} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
    </Route>
  </div>
)
```

Внимение на контейнер "Publication" и на компонент "PublicationList".
Пользователь перешел по url /publications/list, сперва отработал естественно контейнер "Publication", где ему в this.props.children передается дочерний компонент "PublicationList". 
Ествественно в "Publication" в рендере есть {this.props.children}

Теперь вопрос, при инициализации контейнера "Publication", он получает начальное состояние, Как передать нужные данные из стейта в компонент {this.props.children}(PublicationList)?

Конечно есть компоненты внутри "Publication", которым можно передать состояние напрямую в props: и все работает, но как быть с динамическими компонентами, которые подключаются в зависимости от url?

Я пока не уточнял возможно ли это, добавить роуты и в контейнер "Publication", но мне кажется это приведет к хаосу, так как удобно, когда все роуты в одном файле и ты знаешь каким компонентом/контейнером отвечает приложение.

Вообщем как то так, прошу ткнуть, так как информацию не нашел.

UPD:
Неужели придется компоненты в контейнеры переводить и для каждого из них создавать свой редьюсер, экшен, константы? это же наплодит столько файлов.

Как вы решаете данный вопрос?

Comment: Если используется редакс, то не совсем понятно, зачем нужно писать редьюсеры, экшн и прочее, чтобы получить стейт в виде пропсов